# My 3 month old Persian kitten has protruding black mole kind of thing? What could it be?

Tags: cats, health, skin-condition

Last week, I started noticing a black dot on my Persian kitten near his whiskers (see the picture attached). What could it be? Could it be black acne?

Today when I came back from work, it has actually protruded out little bit and the mole is little bit dry. Any idea what could it be? I am attaching the picture if somebody has any idea.

Warm regards,
Aravind

[image]

[image: Black mole near his nose]

Comment: Is it actually attached to the skin or can you rub it off? The first picture looks like my dog after he ate messily. Sometimes bits of food and saliva get stuck near his mouth and form black clumbs that I can rub off with a damp paper towel.

Comment: Hello, Nop it is somehow stuck near his whiskers and actually growing. I am taking him to the vet today.

Comment: Hello Everyone, Just wanted to give an update. We were at the Vet already. Its some kind of tick that was sucking blood. The Vet removed and now it is gone. Thank you everyone :)

Comment: Glad it was so simple. If your cat is outdoors, please treat it preventively for intestinal parasites. Some products can prevent infestation with fleas and ticks as well. They have to be refreshed regularily (4 - 6 months) but are worth it for the health of your kitty.

Comment: Hello Elmy,  For intestinal parasites, I have to get deworming right ? I got this medicine also from vet. I have the vet this also.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP indicated that the problem was solved or is no longer relevant and the question details are so specific that it's unlikely to be of use for other people.